React Recharts: is it possible to display a chart in an email?
We are using React Recharts to build charts in an application. We also have a requirement to render a chart in an email. We are using a C# microservice running in Kubernetes to send emails. Is it possible to render a chart in C# and put it in an email?

It depends on how you are authoring the emails. If you are formatting them a Html or RTF, then yes. If they are simple TXT then you will have to add the image as an attachment.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes yes we are formatting them using Html templates. So how do you suggest we accomplish this?

Displaying a chart generated with React Recharts directly in an email poses some challenges due to the limitations of most email clients, which do not support JavaScript code.
React and Recharts rely on JavaScript to create dynamic, interactive charts, and this functionality is not supported by many email clients.
Tools like node-html-to-image or html2canvas can help capture your chart component as an image.

We have decided to go this route, thanks @usama
